# How to integrate Shopify with React native (Android and IOS)?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, shopify

I have read many blogs which mentioned about how to integrate Shopify with React native application.

I'm developing an Android and IOS application with React native framework, I have a confusion likely:
Can I able to embed my application in Shopify or any way to integrate Shopify UI in react native application.

I have followed the below link but getting an error while running the project.
[Build a Shopify App with Node and React](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/set-up-your-app)

If anybody integrated or any idea about the integration of Shopify please help.
Thanks in advance. Help will be appreciated

Using Firebase as a backend to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [js-buy-sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk) for shopify with React native application.